# Android Google Maps - how to set the zoom level (and center) of map to display all my geoobjects?

Tags: android, google-maps

I use google api 2.2. How should I set zoom level(maybe center as well) to display all my geo-objects from ArrayList or Array? I should be dependent on landscape/portrait orientation and maybe screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that computing min and max for latitude/longitude will not be complicated in your array ;-)

```
m_Map.getController().zoomToSpan(
        maxLatitude() - minlatitude(),
        maxLongitude() - minLongitude());
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple approach I have followed:
1. Find the distance between the two Geo points. Use Loc1.distanceTo(Loc2) to get the distance between them.
2. Based on the distance, you can use the below code to set the zoom level. You may have to improvise on the below code to support all screen sizes.

if (fDistance>0 && fDistance<=0.5) {

iZoomLevel = 18;

} else if (fDistance>0.5 && fDistance<=2) {

iZoomLevel = 17;

} else if (fDistance>2 && fDistance<=3) {

iZoomLevel = 15;

} else if (fDistance>3 && fDistance<=10) {

iZoomLevel = 14;

} else if (fDistance>10 && fDistance<=50) {

iZoomLevel = 11;

} else if (fDistance>50 && fDistance<=100) {

iZoomLevel = 9;

} else if (fDistance>100 && fDistance<=300) {

iZoomLevel = 8;

} else if (fDistance>300 && fDistance<=1000) {

iZoomLevel = 7;

} else if (fDistance>1000 && fDistance<=3000) {

iZoomLevel = 5;

} else if (fDistance>3000 && fDistance<=5000) {

iZoomLevel = 4;

} else if (fDistance>5000 && fDistance<=10000) {

iZoomLevel = 3;

}